# GraphQL with Amplify gives 401 Unauthorised for React App (Before and After Adding Auth with Cognito)

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I am trying with Amplify and trying to create my first react application, to just fetch simple Ride model.

I am always getting 401 unauthorised error on localhost and after hosting to S3.

```
errorType: "UnauthorizedException"
message: "You are not authorized to make this call."
```

Comment: did you resolve this?  I've just come accross this issue and found my AppSync key had expired. The Default is 7 days. I added a new key in AWS AppSync > MyApp > Settings and added the generated key to my aws-exports.js file for value "aws_appsync_apikey" and it worked fine in local dev. Mine still gives a 401 error when deployed to AWS tho'

Answer (score -1):

@SlackGadget's solution was essentially correct.

The default expiration time of the AppSync API key is 7 day, meaning if you do not set this in your initial congif of your Amplify build or use a different type of authentication, then your API will expire after 7 days. If you deploy within this timeframe then a new key is generated, but there is no real warning without checking AppSync.

**To check follow these steps:**

1. Go to AWS AppSync
2. Click on the app in question
3. Click Settings in the side nav
4. Check the key against what appears in your `aws-exports.js` file, if it has expired this will be the issue.

**Solution:**

1. To initially fix it, re-deploy you app from the Amplify console to get it up and running an prevent the 401 error
2. Then update the API locally, go to your `<project-root>/amplify/backend/api/<api-name>/parameters.json` file and add a `APIKeyExpirationEpoch` key. This take an expiration time in seconds of the key. You can then deploy this and the new key will have a new expiration date.
3. You can also update the expiration key in the AppSync setting

Here are the docs for overwriting the Amplify parameters: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/resolvers/#custom-resolvers